# Check for template class equality through base class pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, polymorphism, subclass

Is it possible to check, through a base class pointer, whether different derived template classes are specialization of the same template class?

This is achievable through introducing an intermediate non-template base-class. However, i would like to know whether this pattern is avoidable when the sole purpose of this intermediate class is for identification:

```
class A{}

class B_base : public A{}

template<T>
class B : public B_base {}

// There may be other derived classes of A
template<T>
class C: public A{}

void main() {
    // ... some vector of pointers to A derived objects
    std::vector<A*> v;

    for(auto& i : v){
        // Check whether i is any specialization of B through a 
        // dynamic_cast to the intermediate class
        if(dynamic_cast<B_base*>()){
            // This is a B_base object, 
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, i would like something like this, to avoid the intermediate class.

```
class A{}

template<T>
class B : public A{}

// There may be other derived classes of A
template<T>
class C: public A{}

void main() {
    // ... some vector of pointers to A derived objects
    std::vector<A*> v;

    for(auto& i : v){
        // Check whether i is any specialization of B
        if(templateTypeId(i) == templateTypeId(B*)){
            // This is a B object with some unknown specialization
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have simplified your code a bit too much: `A` must have at least one virtual function (like the destructor) for `dynamic_cast` to work. Providing [mcve] code prevents distractions from issues unrelated to the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different specializations of a template are entirely unrelated types for most purposes.  Template argument deduction can deduce a template and its arguments from such a type, but that happens entirely at compile time.  There is no guaranteed run time information that can tell whether a class is a specialization of a given template, whether two classes are specializations of the same template, etc.

So you would need to set up a way to test this yourself, but your intermediate class method is not the only option.  The most straightforward way would be to put a way to test it into the base `A` class:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual bool is_B() const noexcept { return false; }
};

template <class T>
class B : public A {
public:
    bool is_B() const noexcept override { return true; }
};
```

Though this gets a bit ugly if there are several different B-like categories to test for, and doesn't work if it should be possible to extend `A` with new subtypes, and then test for those subtypes in a similar way.

Another idea would be to associate the type check with an object address:

```
struct type_tag {
    constexpr type_tag() = default;
    type_tag(const type_tag&) = delete;
    type_tag& operator=(const type_tag&) = delete;
};

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual bool matches_type(const type_tag&) const
    { return false; }
};

inline constexpr type_tag B_tag{};

template <class T>
class B {
public:
    bool matches_type(const type_tag& tag) const override
    { return &tag == &B_tag; }
};
```

This pattern also allows for categories of subtypes that don't come from just one template.  It also doesn't prevent a new class from "lying" about its own type, if that might be a concern, but it might be best not to try to prevent that, but let any implemented derived class be responsible for its own behavior, which might mean it wants to act "almost exactly like" some other type.

Answer (score 0):

May be a better design is to add required virtual functions to interface `A`, so that you can invoke them directly on `A*` without guessing the derived class. The latter is an anti-pattern because it defeats the purpose of polymorphism: the idea that a piece of code can work with object of different classes without knowing their exact type. You may as well put objects of different types into different containers and not use ploymorphism based on virtual functions at all.